# After each word which ends with given substring insert a word

Tags: java, regex

I need after each word of the text, ending with a given substring,
insert the specified word.My code works to some extent, I think it is not good idea modifying StringBuilder object while iterating over it. As you can see it fails in the last two cases, with "kalola" and "lalilo". Thanks a lot!

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TextEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Hello Mister James! Do you use trello fregiently? "
                + "Do you know Canelo Pavelo magenta ravelo sagenta! "
                + "lolita kalola lalilo lalita 333l lo.";

        String regex = "\\b\\w+lo\\b";

        String word = " 232 ";

        StringBuilder copyOfText = new StringBuilder(text);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(copyOfText);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            copyOfText.insert(matcher.end(), word);
        }

        //text = copyOfText.toString();

        System.out.println(copyOfText);
    }
}
```

Received output is:

> Hello 232  Mister James! Do you use trello 232  fregiently? Do you
>   know Canelo 232  Pavelo 232  magenta ravelo 232  sagenta! lolita kalo
>   232 la lalilo lalita 333l lo.

Expected output is:

> Hello 232  Mister James! Do you use trello 232  fregiently? Do you
>   know Canelo 232  Pavelo 232  magenta ravelo 232  sagenta! lolita
>   kalola lalilo 232 lalita 333l lo.

Comment: Why not just use replaceAll instead of a while loop?

Comment: [Your regex is fine](https://regex101.com/r/Fro6Uo/1), your logic isn't. As @CAustin mentioned, use replaceAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead of iterating with a while loop:

```
String text = "Hello Mister James! Do you use trello fregiently? "
        + "Do you know Canelo Pavelo magenta ravelo sagenta! "
        + "lolita kalola lalilo lalita 333l lo.";

String word = "232";

System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(\\w+lo\\b)", "$1 " + word));
```

Output:

> Hello 232 Mister James! Do you use trello 232 fregiently? Do you know
>   Canelo 232 Pavelo 232 magenta ravelo 232 sagenta! lolita kalola lalilo
>   232 lalita 333l lo.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What do dollar sign and number mean here "$1 "?

Comment: The regex in the parentheses is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). The `$1` is to include the captured group in the replacement string. If you don't include it then all matched words ("Hello", "trello"...) would be entirely replaced by "232".

Comment: You don't need a capturing group in this situation. You just refer to the full match. Just do `text.replaceAll("\\w+lo\\b", "$0 " + word)` this saves a few characters.

Comment: More, it will work in a very unexpected way if `word` contains literal ``\`` or `$0`/`$1` substrings.